# higher version than referenced assembly

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, assemblies

Im getting this error:

```
Error   101 Assembly 'EPiServer.Web.WebControls, Version=6.1.379.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7' uses 'EPiServer, Version=6.1.379.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'EPiServer, Version=5.2.375.236, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fe83dea738b45b7'  c:\EPiServer\Sites\suntliv 6.2\bin\EPiServer.Web.WebControls.dll    SuntLiv.Web
```

Does it mean that the assembly EPiServer.Web.WebControls calls for EPiServer DLL version 6.1.379.0 but only finds EpiServer DLL version 5.2.375.236?

Comment: You need to add version 6.1.379.0 dll instead of 5.2.375.236

Answer (score 1):

The first comment says it all. It was not properly referenced.